# KrollWrapper ids filling all text for all Data Binding in Alloy 1.8.2

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Since upgrading to alloy 1.8.2 all of my ListViews are having text filled in with KrollWrapper ids in place of the data I am trying to bind. I have tried all kinds of things and nothing has changed this at all, is there something I am missing?  My data binding is set up like the documentation explains and has worked flawlessly up till now.  I have tried it with and without the transform function in the model and with and without the data transform function defined in the controler and I have many lists and this is happening on many, and the other are now blank.

Also I do not know how to roll Alloy back so it will work again(was working on 5.2.0), how might I do that?

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtsdV.png)

Comment: This might be related to [this known issue](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1474), but as the result is different, could you please leave a comment on the JIRA ticket with a reproducible test case?

Comment: I have copied and pasted one sample to a new app, however it works fine separated out, I will keep working on it, but is it possible that the size of the app could be contributing to this issue?  The app in question is fairly large.  Also I tried it against 1.8.3 and that had the same result, but switching to 1.7.33(from 5.2.0) and everything was working properly again.

Comment: If you could somehow get me access to the project that would be great. Clearly something's going on and the size of the app shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: Working on getting clearance to get you the source code, but as of now I have tried both 1.8.4 and 1.8.5 and the issue presists, a couple other things about our code, they are instance collections

Comment: Also I know the collection is running through the transform function ok, I have put the result in the console and I can see all the data correctly after running through and before returning.

Comment: So doing some comparisons of the 2 generated files, the ones that stand out the most are:

1.7.33

 `name: {text: "undefined" != typeof __alloyId419.__transform["Name"] ? __alloyId419.__transform["Name"] : __alloyId419.get("Name")}`

Compared to 1.8.5

`name: {  text: _.template("{m.Name}", {
                        m: __alloyId419.__transform
                    }, {
                        interpolate: /\{([\s\S]+?)\}/g
                    })}`

and this is true of all the values I am attempting to put in a list item.

Comment: Mike, in your transform method, what do you get if you log before you return? Are the attributes you have issues with objects perhaps? Then that's https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1480

Comment: @Fokke  nope:
` {
       DueDate = "April 1, 2016";
       EndDate = "2016-04-01";
       ID = 6918;
       Name = "Test 1 Z [03-31-2016]";
       RecurringType = "6 ";
       ReferenceNumber = "Reference #935-65";
       dueColor = "#575858";
       mPlanType = standard;
       numLocations = 5;
   }`

Comment: Mike, could you try with Alloy 1.8.5 (part of CLI 5.2.2) and if it is still an issue create a JIRA ticket with a reproducing test case (app)? Thanks!

Comment: 1.8.5 also has the same issue

Comment: Thanks for checking Mike. Could you get met a reproducing test case?

Comment: Working on it....once removed from the larger context of the app everything seems to work.  In the past I have run  into variable name collisions in projects with alloy, I am beginning to wonder if this is something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the vast majority of our problems where from having a different version of underscore in the lib/alloy folder.  After removing that file and using the included underscore version almost all of our issues went away including all the KrollWarapper issues described above.